# how to linq query spfield to spuser

Tags: linq

Here is my code.

```
SPUser approver = mySite.EnsureUser(approverId);
var selectedItems = listItems.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(p => p.Fields["WF_Approver"] == approver);
```

my list items field "WF_Approver" is field type of person or group.
my approver is type of SPUser.

So how can i check the equation here between SPField and SPUser ?

btw

```
p.Fields["WF_Approver"].ToString()==approver.loginname
```

didn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this to get the SPUser from the field:

```
SPUser userFromField = 
    new SPFieldUserValue(web, p.Fields["WF_Approver"].ToString());
```

Where `web` is the current SPWeb

Comment: Thanks that casting didn't work but inspired me inanother way,i solved it like this
p["WF_Approver"].ToString()==approver.loginname 
it is very easy but at that time i couldn't think this.